# Database to store compressed files

Tags: mysql, database, redis, storage, bigdata

We use Redis database as:

```
key -> (file1, file2, file3)
```

The value is always a list of three compressed files.

Not all the keys have the 3 files i.e.

```
key2 -> (file4, file5)
```

Files are compressed using zlib.
Size of file is between 50 - 120 K compressed.

I want to store the "complete" keys (the ones with 3 files in the list) ,
in a database.

Until now I was storing the data in a MySQL table :

```
key_id : INTEGER , PRIMARY KEY
first : BLOB
second : BLOB
third : BLOB
```

This works pretty fine with the exception of slow inserts
(Mysql Server does at the same time other things).

I will query the data very rare but I want to be able to get them
one by one easily.

Redis is a database and I know I can dump to a file (rdb files).

So I think it is redudancy to use another DBMS.
But the redis database is memory limited, so I can not just
wait to finish the production of the values (files) and then 
just dump to an rdb file.

I would like to create smaller rdb files that contain 
only the "complete" keys.
i.e

at time 1 the redis contains the following:

```
key3 -> (a, b, c)
key14 -> (e, f)
key1 -> (g, h, i)
```

then if I decide to dump the dump file into 1.rdb should contain only:

```
key3 and key14
```

If the dump is successful I will delete the dumped keys (key3, key4)

and the redis should have:

```
key14 -> (e, f)
```

Now in time 5 the redis contains:

```
key5 -> (i, j , k)
key14 -> (d, e, f)
key6 -> (l, m)
```

So if I save to 2.rdb the file should contain only:

key5, key14

and then the above keys should be deleted from redis.

Is that possible? I am using python if it matters.

Do you have another idea for this task?
Another DBMS , store direct to filesystem etc.

P.S Forgot to mention that in total there would be around 
15.000.000 keys so there would be 15.000.000 * 3 files.

Also I use Linux with ext3 filesystem

Comment: You might be able to use the new (in redis 2.6) [MIGRATE](http://redis.io/commands/migrate) command to migrate, i.e. move, those keys to another database, and then [SAVE](http://redis.io/commands/save) that database.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to keep everything in one system.  Do you really need Redis to manage the keysets?  A database table that gets accessed frequently should stay mostly cached in memory.